# Can I send notifications using WNS without registering my windows 8.1 app to the app store

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Hi I want to add notifications to my Windows 8.1 application. I have been doing some research on this topic and the first thing I am told to do is in order to set up my app to receive notifications I need to authenticate the app with WNS but to do this my app must be registered to the Windows store. This is something I would rather not do. So is there a way I can authenticate with WNS without the windows store?

Comment: How would you expect to deploy your app, if not via the store?

Comment: I sideload the application to the relevant devices

Answer (score 1):

You will need to register the app with the Windows Store Dashboard. WNS uses that registration to address the notifications to find the app.

You do not need to upload or deploy the app through the store. The app name reservation on the store will expire if the app isn't published, but the ID needed for WNS to find your app will remain.

You can use the registered credentials with your side-loaded app so long as you sign the app with a certificate that matches the publisher name assigned by the Windows Store and which is trusted on your PCs.

See the note in the [Deploying enterprise apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657971.aspx) documentation.